# How prove $a_{n}=[\sqrt{2}n]+[\sqrt{5}n]$ Contains infinitely even numbers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

> let sequence $$a_{n}=[\sqrt{2}n]+[\sqrt{5}n]$$
>
> where $[x]$  is  the largest integer not greater than $x$
>
> show that  $\{a_{n}\}$  Contains infinitely   even numbers.
>
> also I guess contains infinitely odd numbers.

before I have ask this [How prove this sequence $S_{n}=[2^n\cdot \sqrt{2}],n\in N$ contains infinitely many composite numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/749651/how-prove-this-sequence-s-n-2n-cdot-sqrt2-n-in-n-contains-infinitely-m)

I found :
 $$a_{2}=[2\sqrt{2}]+[2\sqrt{5}]=2+4=6$$
$$a_{3}=[3\sqrt{2}]+[3\sqrt{5}]=4+6=10$$
$$a_{5}=[5\sqrt{2}]+[5\sqrt{5}]=7+11=18$$
$$a_{7}=[7\sqrt{2}]+[7\sqrt{5}]=9+15=24$$
$$a_{8}=[8\sqrt{2}]+[8\sqrt{5}]=11+17=28$$
$$a_{9}=[9\sqrt{2}]+[9\sqrt{5}]=12+20=32$$
$$a_{10}=[10\sqrt{2}]+[10\sqrt{5}]=14+22=36$$
$$a_{12}=[12\sqrt{2}]+[12\sqrt{5}]=16+26=42$$
$$a_{14}=[14\sqrt{2}]+[14\sqrt{5}]=19+31=50$$
$$a_{15}=[15\sqrt{2}]+[15\sqrt{5}]=21+33=54$$

and so on
 this problem is my found it. It seem this is interesting problem,and How prove it?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to avoid the standard floor function notation? $$a_n=\lfloor\sqrt 2 n\rfloor+\lfloor\sqrt 5 n\rfloor$$ or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: following I explain where$\cdots $..

Comment: Yes, indeed! That part sounds like the floor function to me. I just asked if you deliberately avoided conventional notation for it. So this is merely a suggestion of changing $[x]$ to $\lfloor x\rfloor$, if you agree. But if you want to keep the current notation, I have no problem with that.

Comment: @String: Why do you think that floor is more standard than square brackets? That's news to me.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: OK, sorry both of you! I have seen both uses too, but I personally prefer the floor-notation since it seems unambiguous. The square brackets are used as normal brackets now and then and maybe even to denote the ceiling function at times? But I am certainly no expert regarding the general usage of such notation. Perhaps the latex code \lfloor and \rfloor along with the name of the notaiton is misleading me :o)

Comment: @String: The point of relieving square brackets for other use does make sense. May be this is a generational thing and in my youth there was no way to typeset floors :-) Anyway, the context does make it clear, at least most of the time, whether square brackets are used as regular parens or denoting this function.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks! I take it this usage of square brackets can even appear nostalgic to some people? Interesting for me to learn how others use it and think of it. I also prefer square brackets over the notation $$\text{floor}(\sqrt 2 n)+\text{floor}(\sqrt 5 n)$$ any time, although this last version has the advantage of being almost self-explanatory!

Answer (score 5):

When you increase $n$ by one, $\lfloor \sqrt 2 n \rfloor$ increases by either $1$ (with frequency $2-\sqrt 2$ ) or $2$ (with frequency $\sqrt 2 - 1$), while $\lfloor\sqrt 5n \rfloor$ does by either $2$ (with frequency $3-\sqrt 5$) or $3$ (with frequency $\sqrt 5 - 2$).
If your sequence only contains finitely many odd (or even) terms, then it has to increase by $4$ at every step past a certain point.

This means that whenever $\lfloor\sqrt2 n\rfloor$ increases by $2$ (resp. $1$), $[\sqrt 5 n\rfloor$ increases by $2$ (resp. $3$).
However, the frequency at which those increments occur are all different. Therefore this is impossible, and so you must obtain infinitely many even / odd terms .

You can make this proof more precise and show that there can't be more than $4$ consecutive terms of the same parity.